# How to add _id automatically to an array of object in nestjs mongoose

Tags: mongoose, nested, nestjs, schema

I want to add _id automatically to all object inside an array.I am using mongoose with nestjs framework.

**my schema looks like**

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
export type PropModel = newSchemaDetail & Document;
@Schema()
export class Prop3 {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  prop3.1: string;
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  prop3.2: string;
}
@Schema()
export class Prop4{
@Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  prop4.1: string;
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  prop4.2: string;}

@Schema()
export class newSchemaDetail {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  prop1: string;
  @Prop({ type: String, required: false }) 
  prop2: string;
  @Prop({ type: Array<Prop3>, required: true })
  prop3: Prop3[];
 @Prop({ type: Prop3, required: true }) 
prop4:Prop4
 
}
export const PropSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(newSchemaDetail);
```

**result**

```
{
  "prop1": "xyz",
  "prop2": "abc",
  "prop3": [
    {
      "prop3.1": "kgkhkmfe",
      "prop3.2": "nbjfmlkgh"
    }
  ],
  "prop4":{"_id":"646b99d74abf7c25e21tx85","prop4.1":"test","prop4.2":"test2"},
  "_id": "646c99e74bcf7b25d21cyb85",
  "__v": 0
}
```

**expected**

```
{
  "prop1": "xyz",
  "prop2": "abc",
  "prop3": [
    {
      "_id":"646b99d47abf7c56e21tx89"
      "prop3.1": "kgkhkmfe",
      "prop3.2": "nbjfmlkgh"
    }
  ],
  "prop4":{"_id":"646b99d74abf7c25e21tx85","prop4.1":"test","prop4.2":"test2"},
  "_id": "646c99e74bcf7b25d21cyb85",
  "__v": 0
}
```

Why `@Schema()` is not working with array of object or am I doing something wrong.Can anyone tell how to get my expected result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try `@Prop({ type: [Prop3], required: true })` instead of `@Prop({ type: Array<Prop3>, required: true })`

Comment: I have tried before i was getting  error throw new TypeError('Invalid schema configuration: ' +
              ^
TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `Prop3` is not a valid type within the array `prop3` error

Comment: Did you check the answers below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should create a schema for Prop3 like this:

```
const Prop3Schema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Prop3);
```

And replace the line `@Prop({ type: Array<Prop3>, required: true })` with the following.

```
@Prop({ type: [Prop3Schema], required: true })
```

Comment: @varshakumari can you please mark as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend from `AbstractDocument`

```
export class Prop3 extends AbstractDocument {
    //
}
```